# Opera and Safari do not fire image.onload

Tags: javascript, image, safari, dom-events, opera

```
function controllaFoto(target, username) {
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        if(this.width > 240 || this.height > 240) {
            document.getElementById("photoLabel").innerHTML = "Text";
            document.getElementById("preview").setAttribute("src", "profile?to=showImage&username="+username);
            target.value = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("photoLabel").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("preview").setAttribute("src", this.src);
        }
    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(target.files[0]);
    return true;
}
```

This script is called by the `onchange` and `onsubmit` attributes and works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Opera and Safari. The event `onload` is not triggered. Why?

**UPDATE** I'm testing it with Windows.

**UPDATE 2** The problem is that `_URL` is `undefined`. I tried with

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL || window.oURL;
```

but still not working.

For Chrome its value is `object DOMURL`, for Firefox is `object MozURLProperty`, but for Safari and Opera is `undefined`. So the console says:

> Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert '_URL' to object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL), it doesn't look like `createObjectURL` is supported in Opera or in some versions of Safari.  That alone may be your main issue.  Have you looked in the error console to see if it's complaining about the lack of the `createObjectURL` method.  If that method doesn't exist, you would never get an assignment to `.src` so thus there would never be a successful load event.

In addition, I can't say for sure, but this also looks like a potential issue to me.  You may need to store the newly create Image object somewhere so it persists.  The way your code is written above, the garbage collector may be free to dispose of the img object because there are no longer any references to it.

Perhaps you haven't shown us all of your code, but as you have it written, what's the point of loading an image that you will never use?

So, I'd suggest either change the way your code works to not use an image that you aren't going to use.  Or, actual store the newly create img tag somewhere so it persists and won't get garbage collected.

I'd also ask how you know that the image is loading successfully?  If you're not using the image, how do you know it's successfully loading.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I posted just a part of the script. Before I check the file `ContentType`, so I'm sure that it is an image. I need to check its width and height to warn the user that he cannot upload such an image. If all controls are passed, then the user can upload it using the apposite form. About the lack of the `createObjectURL` method, Eclipse does not show me any error (if its is the right console to check).

Comment: I don't know Eclipse, but I would assume that the error console you need to be looking in is in the browser.  You need to see run-time errors.  It should be showing you that `_URL` does not contain a method named `createObjectURL` or the `_URL` itself is undefined.

Comment: I edited my question. Opera Dragonfly debug console says that `_URL` is `undefined`.